# $addFields is not adding value in document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Query is as follows and result is given below:

 What I want is I am adding field called name, in which I want categoryObj[0].categoryName but it is empty.

 Tried `categoryObj.$.categoryName` but giving error.

 Once name is obtained as I want i will exclude categoryObj with project opertator.

 **Thanks for help in advance**

```
let itemsByCategory = await VendorItem.aggregate([            
            {$match: {vendor: vendorId}},
            {$lookup: {
                from: "vendorcategories",
                localField: "category",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: 'categoryDetails'
            }},
            {$group:{
                "_id":"$category",
                "count":{"$sum":1},
                "items":{"$push":"$$ROOT"},
                "categoryObj":{"$addToSet":"$categoryDetails"}
            }},
            {$project: {"items.categoryDetails":0}},
            {$addFields: {"categoryName" : "$categoryObj.categoryName"}},
            //{$project: {"categoryObj":0}},
        ]);
```

and the result is as follows

```
{
    "itemsByCategory": [
        {
            "_id": "62296d612a1462a7d5e4b86b",
            "count": 1,
            "menuItems": [
                {
                    "_id": "622971fa4fda7b4c792a7812",
                    "category": "62296d612a1462a7d5e4b86b",
                    "vendor": "62296c6f2a1462a7d5e4b863",
                    "item": "Dahi Chaat",
                    "price": 30,
                    "inStock": true,
                    "variants": [
                        {
                            "variantName": "With Sev",
                            "variantPrice": 40,
                            "_id": "622975b9f7bdf6c2a3b7703c"
                        }
                    ],
                    "toppings": [
                        {
                            "name": "cheese",
                            "price": 10,
                            "inStock": true,
                            "_id": "62297766ff9f01d236c60736"
                        }
                    ],
                    "categoryDetails": [
                        {
                            "_id": "62296d612a1462a7d5e4b86b",
                            "categoryName": "Snacks",
                            "categoryDescription": "Desciption changed!",
                            "vendor": "621c6c944d6d79e83219e59a",
                            "__v": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "categoryObj": [
                [
                    {
                        "_id": "62296d612a1462a7d5e4b86b",
                        "categoryName": "Snacks",
                        "categoryDescription": "Desciption changed!",
                        "vendor": "621c6c944d6d79e83219e59a",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ]
            ],
            "name": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try using `$arrayElemAt` aggregate operator to access an array filed's element at an index.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an $unwind phase in order to "loop" all objects inside "categoryObj", but you will need to group it back afterwards:

```
{"$addFields": {orig_id: "$_id"}},
{"$unwind": "$categoryObj"},
{"$addFields": {"name": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$categoryObj", 0]}}},
{"$group": {_id: "$orig_id",  name: {$push: "$name.categoryName"},
  menuItems: {$first: "$menuItems"}, count: {$first: "count"},
}
```

}

See playground here:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/wsH2Y0UZ_FH